# Check if certain value exists in array of hash map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hashmap

I have an array of hash map. It looks like this:

```
params = []
CSV.foreach(......) do
  one_line_item = {}
  one_line_item[:sku] = "Hello"
  one_line_item[:value] = "20000"
  params << one_line_item
end
```

I want to check if `:sku` is in this array of hash or not. I am doing it like this:

```
# Reading new line of csv in a hash and saving it in a temporary variable (Say Y)
params.each do |p|
  if p[:sku] == Y[:sku]
    next
  end
end
```

I am iterating through the complete list for every value of sku, and thus time complexity is going for a toss [O(n^2)], need less to say it is useless.

Is there a way I can use `include?`?

If I can get an array of values corresponding to the key `:sku` from the whole array in one shot, it would solve my problem. (I know I can maintain another array for these values but I want to avoid that)

One example of params

```
params = [{:sku=>"hello", :value=>"5000"}, {:sku=>"world", :value=>"6000"}, {:sku=>"Hi", :value=>"7000"}]
```

Comment: can you please post an example of populated `params`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) and [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-include-3F) methods sound like what you need.

Example:

```
params.any? { |param| param.include?(:sku) }
```

This is an efficient way to do it, as it "short circuits", stopping as soon as a match is found.

Comment: Going with some thing similar 

"params.any? { |p| p.values.member?("hello") }"

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to collect a list of all SKUs. Are you looking to key sku => value?

```
Hash[*params.map { |p| [p[:sku], p[:value]] }.flatten]
```

That will give you a map of each sku to the value, which you can then do quick key lookups with sku_hash.key?(tester)

Answer (score 0):

You may use **rails_param** gem for doing the same. I find it a very useful utility for validation request params in controller:

https://github.com/nicolasblanco/rails_param

```
# primitive datatype syntax
param! :integer_array, Array do |array,index|
  array.param! index, Integer, required: true
end

# complex array
param! :books_array, Array, required: true  do |b|
  b.param! :title, String, blank: false
  b.param! :author, Hash, required: true do |a|
    a.param! :first_name, String
    a.param! :last_name, String, required: true
  end
  b.param! :subjects, Array do |s,i|
    s.param! i, String, blank: false
  end
end
```